# Native query hibernate increasing heap size

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, heap-memory

My application have lots of native queries, and each query is different as it contains query like DATE(cl.placement_time) = CURDATE(), which I think always results in cache miss of hibernate. Because as per I know whenever there is change in query then hibernate consider it as different.

I also applied below properties to avoid caching or limit same.

> spring.jpa.hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size=16 spring.jpa.hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size=16 spring.jpa.hibernate.cache.use_query_cache=false spring.jpa.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false

But there is no change after this, is there any other way to limit the heap used. I already provided 24GB as max heap and now used heap is reaching 20 GB.

Comment: Did you use a profiler? To see where the memory is going.

Comment: Sounds like a leak. Analyzing a HeapDump will help, but don't wait for heap to be at 20GB before dumping ...

Comment: yes, I took heap dump for staging env, it's contains char[] having SQL queries.

Comment: came to know that my old gen is continuously increasing, any way to configure major gc?

Comment: Did you find a solutoin for this? I am having a same problem